# Access Spring placeholder inside servlet during start up

Tags: java, spring, servlets, configuration

In an spring framework base application (with struts not SpringMVC), we want to read the spring place holders in a `servlet` during web application start up and put it in application scope.

I found that I can not use `@Value` in `servlet` which implements `ServletContextListener`.

This seems correct as Spring do not aware of the `servlet` startup. I used below code for that

```
@WebListener
public class StartUp implements ServletContextListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(StartUp.class);
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        //As the servlet starts outside spring application context The @Value can not
        //be used to inject values
        //The Spring beanFactory class can be used to get values from property files.
        //This is same as using @value.
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());

        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext)
                .getBeanFactory();

        String template = beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue("${site.active.template}");
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("TEMPLATE", template );

        LOG.debug("Current template is : {}",template );
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        LOG.debug("Webapplcaition destroyed");
    }

}
```

I am not an spring guy, so please let me know if there is better approach. 
Also, is there a better way to access `beanFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple search shows the plugin for struts for this purpose:

```
<plug-in className="org.springframework.web.struts.ContextLoaderPlugIn">
        <set-property property="contextConfigLocation"
            value="/WEB-INF/context.xml" />
    </plug-in>
```

Comment: Deprecated in Spring 3.0 and I could not find it in Spring 4 jars, may be removed. Also I think it is for struts 1.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi It was not easy to find it again. [Spring-struts](http://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html)